# Show most occured in rank order #

Tags: c#, ranking

I have a list consisting of duplicates, I want to create an output showing them in rank. e.g tom at the top because he has 100 entries and lilly at the bottom because it has 0.

is this possible to display a list with a rank corosponding to the number of times they appear in the list?

also display the number of times they appear next to them?

Comment: What sort of data structure are you using?  This can be done in many ways; the easiest is probably to use a "Bucket Sort" for this type of thing.

Comment: "and lilly at the bottom because it has 0": now this really blew my mind...

Comment: Lilly only appears once, however tom appears 100 times so in effect i want to count the number of times it appears and display them in that rank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var query = File
    .ReadLines("input.txt")
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .Select(g => new { Key = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
    .OrderByDescending(i => i.Count)
    .Take(20);

foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0,5} {1}", item.Count, item.Key);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to just show the first 20 lines of the result?

Comment: @Evildommer5: Yes. I've expanded my answer.

Comment: This does not compile .Take isnt in the System.IO

Comment: @Evildommer5: Take, GroupBy, Select and OrderByDescending require .NET 3.5 (or later) *and* a `using System.Linq;` directive in your source file.

Comment: Im using system.linq. is this because im using an old framework? any alternatives?

Comment: Groupby and select are working, however take doesn't appear is there an alternativE?

Comment: Please include the .NET version in your question if it's so ancient that it doesn't support LINQ.

Comment: I resvoled the issue the fomatting was wrong just needed to recopy it back in. thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

The following will give an `IEnumerable` where each item contains a representative item from the group and the number of times it occurs.

```
myList
    .GroupBy( item => item.Name )
    .OrderByDescending( g => g.Count() )
    .Select( g => new {item=g.First(), numOcurrences=g.Count() )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var groups = list.GroupBy(item => item);
var orderedGroups = groups.OrderByDescending(group => group.Count());
foreach (var group in orderedGroups)
{
  Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}", group.Key, group.Count());
}
```

Comment: VC 74- i recived a error saying, link does not appear in current context. any suggestions?

Comment: @Evildommer5, please add a using for System.Linq.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple LINQ query that does remotely that.

```
List<string> list = new List<string> { "a", "b", "a", "c", "a", "d", "c" };
var counts = from item in list
             group item by item
                 into grp
                 orderby grp.Count() descending
                 select new
                            {
                                Value = grp.Key,
                                Count = grp.Count()
                            };
foreach (var item in counts)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", item.Value, item.Count);
```